# Django ModelForm Form not Posting

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that is based on a ModelForm in my forms.py.  I initially get the blank form as expected, however when filling out the form and hitting `submit` nothing happens.   I am not sure where I am going wrong.

views.py

```
def add_customer(request):
    # print(customer_form)
    # print(customer_form.errors)
    print(request.method)
    print(request.POST)
    customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)
    if customer_form.is_valid() and request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return redirect('AdminPortal:customers')
        print('posted')
    else:
        print('failing')
        context = {'customer_form': customer_form,}
        return render(request, 'add_customer.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
    path("customers/", views.customers, name="customers"),
    path("customers/customer/<int:id>/", views.customer, name="customer"),
    path("add_customer/", views.add_customer, name="add_customer"),
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AppCustomerCst
        fields = ('is_active_cst', 'name_cst', 'address_1_cst', 'address_2_cst', 'address_3_cst',
                  'city_cst', 'state_cst', 'zip_cst', 'country_cst', 'salesrep_cst', 'type_cst',
                  'is_allowed_flat_cst', 'iddef_cst', 'balance_notify_cst',  'receive_emails_cst',
                  'contact_domain_cst'
                  )
```

add_customer.py [form portion]

```
    <form method="post" action='AdminPortal:add_customer'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ customer_form }}
        <button type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: `{{form.errors}}` doesn't give me anything.  It's like the `Submit` isn't' hitting anywhere. This was working previously, but I am working on implementing `get_absolute_url` attributes on my models, could that be creating an issue?  Is there a specific way to handle ModelForms when using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error in the HTML Template.
I had:

```
<button type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Once Updated to:

```
        <input type="submit" value="submit">Submit</input>
        <input type="submit" value="cancel">Cancel</input>
```

The form posted properly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the form doesn't know where to post.

You need to turn it into a django `url` template tag. So I'd do something like this for your form;

```
<form method="post" action='{% url "AdminPortal:add_customer" %}'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% endif %}

    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

To find what's happening in your view I'd recommend simplifying the logic somewhat so that it's more inline with the docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views

Because you're doubling up the check for post & valid, I suspect you're never seeing the validation errors because they'd only come from that block of code. So change your view to be something like this and if you updated your template as above you should see some errors;

```py
def add_customer(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('AdminPortal:customers')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()

    return render(request, 'add_customer.html', {'customer_form': form})
```

Comment: thanks again!  No dice, however, still just sits there when the submit button is clicked.  This did work before I employed the `get_absolute_urls` so I'm not sure if that's leading to me needing to update.  This same process works for a different type of modelForm that I haven't updated with `get_absolute_url` yet.

Comment: @AlliDeacon Shouldn't have anything to do with that method on the models. If you view page source, you should be able to confirm that django rendered the correct path as the form action and then if it does, are any of your prints being output from your view? Or is there anything in the server or browser console output that gives a clue as to what happens on submit?

Comment: yes, in the page source it: `<form method="post" action='/add_customer/'>`  I have print statements in my view, but they aren't making it to that part of the code.  The console shows `[17/Sep/2020 11:41:32] "GET /add_customer/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12615` when I initially hit the page, however it doesn't update once I hit the submit

Comment: You are correct, once I added that method to my second record type I'm manipulating, the create and delete both continue to work.  I am going to rebuild and see what I did wrong.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlliDeacon Take a look at the update to my answer. I don't think the form you're returning to the page ever had the errors in because the form had to be valid for the validated form to be returned.

Comment: So...  I'm embarrassed to admit this, but my HTML had a `<button>` and not an `<input>`

Comment: @AlliDeacon ha, yes, so easily overlooked!!