# Django ModelForm Submit button does nothing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-oscar

I have the following ModelForm, UpdateView and template but when I click on the 'Save' button and the 'Save and continue editing' button, nothing happens. I tried following the fix in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939073/django-modelform-form-not-posting) but it didn't work. How do I post the data in these forms into their respective tables?

**forms.py:**

```
class ProductForm(SEOFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    FIELD_FACTORIES = {
        "text": _attr_text_field,
        "richtext": _attr_textarea_field,
        "integer": _attr_integer_field,
        "boolean": _attr_boolean_field,
        "float": _attr_float_field,
        "date": _attr_date_field,
        "datetime": _attr_datetime_field,
        "option": _attr_option_field,
        "multi_option": _attr_multi_option_field,
        "entity": _attr_entity_field,
        "numeric": _attr_numeric_field,
        "file": _attr_file_field,
        "image": _attr_image_field,
    }

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'title', 'upc', 'description', 'is_public', 'is_discountable', 'structure', 'slug', 'meta_title',
            'meta_description']
        widgets = {
            'structure': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'meta_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'no-widget-init'})
        }

    def __init__(self, product_class, metal, data=None, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_initial(product_class, metal, parent, kwargs)
        super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        if parent:
            self.instance.parent = parent
            # We need to set the correct product structures explicitly to pass
            # attribute validation and child product validation. Note that
            # those changes are not persisted.
            self.instance.structure = Product.CHILD
            self.instance.parent.structure = Product.PARENT

            self.delete_non_child_fields()
        else:
            # Only set product class for non-child products
            self.instance.product_class = product_class
            self.instance.metal = metal
        self.add_attribute_fields(product_class, metal, self.instance.is_parent)

        if 'slug' in self.fields:
            self.fields['slug'].required = False
            self.fields['slug'].help_text = _('Leave blank to generate from product title')
        if 'title' in self.fields:
            self.fields['title'].widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'})

    def set_initial(self, product_class, metal, parent, kwargs):
        """
        Set initial data for the form. Sets the correct product structure
        and fetches initial values for the dynamically constructed attribute
        fields.
        """
        if 'initial' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['initial'] = {}
        self.set_initial_attribute_values(product_class, metal, kwargs)
        if parent:
            kwargs['initial']['structure'] = Product.CHILD

    def set_initial_attribute_values(self, product_class, metal, kwargs):
        """
        Update the kwargs['initial'] value to have the initial values based on
        the product instance's attributes
        """
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if instance is None:
            return
        for attribute in product_class.attributes.all():
            try:
                value = instance.attribute_values.get(
                    attribute=attribute).value
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                kwargs['initial']['attr_%s' % attribute.code] = value

        for attribute in metal.product_attribute.all():
            try:
                value = instance.attribute_values.get(
                    attribute=attribute).value
            except exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            else:
                kwargs['initial']['attr_%s' % attribute.code] = value

    def add_attribute_fields(self, product_class, metal, is_parent=False):
        """
        For each attribute specified by the product class, this method
        dynamically adds form fields to the product form.
        """
        for attribute in product_class.attributes.all():
            field = self.get_attribute_field(attribute)
            if field:
                self.fields['attr_%s' % attribute.code] = field
                # Attributes are not required for a parent product
                if is_parent:
                    self.fields['attr_%s' % attribute.code].required = False

        for attribute in metal.product_attribute.all():
            field = self.get_attribute_field(attribute)
            if field:
                self.fields['attr_%s' % attribute.code] = field
                # Attributes are not required for a parent product
                if is_parent:
                    self.fields['attr_%s' % attribute.code].required = False

    def get_attribute_field(self, attribute):
        """
        Gets the correct form field for a given attribute type.
        """
        return self.FIELD_FACTORIES[attribute.type](attribute)

    def delete_non_child_fields(self):
        """
        Deletes any fields not needed for child products. Override this if
        you want to e.g. keep the description field.
        """
        for field_name in ['description', 'is_discountable']:
            if field_name in self.fields:
                del self.fields[field_name]

    def _post_clean(self):
        """
        Set attributes before ModelForm calls the product's clean method
        (which it does in _post_clean), which in turn validates attributes.
        """
        for attribute in self.instance.attr.get_all_attributes():
            field_name = 'attr_%s' % attribute.code
            # An empty text field won't show up in cleaned_data.
            if field_name in self.cleaned_data:
                value = self.cleaned_data[field_name]
                setattr(self.instance.attr, attribute.code, value)
        super()._post_clean()
```

**views.py:**

```
class ProductCreateUpdateView(PartnerProductFilterMixin, UpdateView):

    template_name = 'oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_update.html'
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'

    form_class = ProductForm
    category_formset = ProductCategoryFormSet
    image_formset = ProductImageFormSet
    recommendations_formset = ProductRecommendationFormSet
    stockrecord_formset = StockRecordFormSet

    creating = False
    parent = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.formsets = {'category_formset': self.category_formset,
                         'image_formset': self.image_formset,
                         'recommended_formset': self.recommendations_formset,
                         'stockrecord_formset': self.stockrecord_formset}

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = super().dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.check_objects_or_redirect() or resp

    def check_objects_or_redirect(self):
        """
        Allows checking the objects fetched by get_object and redirect
        if they don't satisfy our needs.
        Is used to redirect when create a new variant and the specified
        parent product can't actually be turned into a parent product.
        """
        if self.creating and self.parent is not None:
            is_valid, reason = self.parent.can_be_parent(give_reason=True)
            if not is_valid:
                messages.error(self.request, reason)
                return redirect('dashboard:catalogue-product-list')

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Filter products that the user doesn't have permission to update
        """
        return self.filter_queryset(Product.objects.all())

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        This parts allows generic.UpdateView to handle creating products as
        well. The only distinction between an UpdateView and a CreateView
        is that self.object is None. We emulate this behavior.

        This method is also responsible for setting self.product_class and
        self.parent.
        """
        self.creating = 'pk' not in self.kwargs
        if self.creating:
            # Specifying a parent product is only done when creating a child
            # product.
            parent_pk = self.kwargs.get('parent_pk')
            if parent_pk is None:
                self.parent = None
                # A product class needs to be specified when creating a
                # standalone product.
                product_class_slug = self.kwargs.get('product_class_slug')
                metal_slug = self.kwargs.get('metal_slug')
                self.product_class = get_object_or_404(
                    ProductClass, slug=product_class_slug)
                self.metal = get_object_or_404(
                    Metal, slug=metal_slug)
            else:
                self.parent = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=parent_pk)
                self.product_class = self.parent.product_class
                self.metal = self.parent.metal

            return None  # success
        else:
            product = super().get_object(queryset)
            self.product_class = product.get_product_class()
            self.parent = product.parent
            self.metal = product.get_metal_type()
            return product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['product_class'] = self.product_class
        ctx['metal'] = self.metal
        ctx['parent'] = self.parent
        ctx['title'] = self.get_page_title()

        for ctx_name, formset_class in self.formsets.items():
            if ctx_name not in ctx:
                ctx[ctx_name] = formset_class(self.product_class,
                                              self.request.user,
                                              instance=self.object)
        return ctx

    def get_page_title(self):
        if self.creating:
            if self.parent is None:
                return _('Create new %(product_class)s product') % {
                    'product_class': self.product_class.name}
            else:
                return _('Create new variant of %(parent_product)s') % {
                    'parent_product': self.parent.title}
        else:
            if self.object.title or not self.parent:
                return self.object.title
            else:
                return _('Editing variant of %(parent_product)s') % {
                    'parent_product': self.parent.title}

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['product_class'] = self.product_class
        kwargs['parent'] = self.parent
        kwargs['metal'] = self.metal
        return kwargs

    def process_all_forms(self, form):
        """
        Short-circuits the regular logic to have one place to have our
        logic to check all forms
        """
        # Need to create the product here because the inline forms need it
        # can't use commit=False because ProductForm does not support it
        if self.creating and form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()

        formsets = {}
        for ctx_name, formset_class in self.formsets.items():
            formsets[ctx_name] = formset_class(self.product_class,
                                               self.request.user,
                                               self.request.POST,
                                               self.request.FILES,
                                               instance=self.object)

        is_valid = form.is_valid() and all([formset.is_valid()
                                            for formset in formsets.values()])

        cross_form_validation_result = self.clean(form, formsets)
        if is_valid and cross_form_validation_result:
            return self.forms_valid(form, formsets)
        else:
            return self.forms_invalid(form, formsets)

    # form_valid and form_invalid are called depending on the validation result
    # of just the product form and redisplay the form respectively return a
    # redirect to the success URL. In both cases we need to check our formsets
    # as well, so both methods do the same. process_all_forms then calls
    # forms_valid or forms_invalid respectively, which do the redisplay or
    # redirect.
    form_valid = form_invalid = process_all_forms

    def clean(self, form, formsets):
        """
        Perform any cross-form/formset validation. If there are errors, attach
        errors to a form or a form field so that they are displayed to the user
        and return False. If everything is valid, return True. This method will
        be called regardless of whether the individual forms are valid.
        """
        return True

    def forms_valid(self, form, formsets):
        """
        Save all changes and display a success url.
        When creating the first child product, this method also sets the new
        parent's structure accordingly.
        """
        if self.creating:
            self.handle_adding_child(self.parent)
        else:
            # a just created product was already saved in process_all_forms()
            self.object = form.save()

        # Save formsets
        for formset in formsets.values():
            formset.save()

        for idx, image in enumerate(self.object.images.all()):
            image.display_order = idx
            image.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def handle_adding_child(self, parent):
        """
        When creating the first child product, the parent product needs
        to be implicitly converted from a standalone product to a
        parent product.
        """
        # ProductForm eagerly sets the future parent's structure to PARENT to
        # pass validation, but it's not persisted in the database. We ensure
        # it's persisted by calling save()
        if parent is not None:
            parent.structure = Product.PARENT
            parent.save()

    def forms_invalid(self, form, formsets):
        # delete the temporary product again
        if self.creating and self.object and self.object.pk is not None:
            self.object.delete()
            self.object = None

        messages.error(self.request,
                       _("Your submitted data was not valid - please "
                         "correct the errors below"))
        ctx = self.get_context_data(form=form, **formsets)
        return self.render_to_response(ctx)

    def get_url_with_querystring(self, url):
        url_parts = [url]
        if self.request.GET.urlencode():
            url_parts += [self.request.GET.urlencode()]
        return "?".join(url_parts)

    def get_success_url(self):
        """
        Renders a success message and redirects depending on the button:
        - Standard case is pressing "Save"; redirects to the product list
        - When "Save and continue" is pressed, we stay on the same page
        - When "Create (another) child product" is pressed, it redirects
          to a new product creation page
        """
        msg = render_to_string(
            'oscar/dashboard/catalogue/messages/product_saved.html',
            {
                'product': self.object,
                'creating': self.creating,
                'request': self.request
            })
        messages.success(self.request, msg, extra_tags="safe noicon")

        action = self.request.POST.get('action')
        if action == 'continue':
            url = reverse(
                'dashboard:catalogue-product', kwargs={"pk": self.object.id})
        elif action == 'create-another-child' and self.parent:
            url = reverse(
                'dashboard:catalogue-product-create-child',
                kwargs={'parent_pk': self.parent.pk})
        elif action == 'create-child':
            url = reverse(
                'dashboard:catalogue-product-create-child',
                kwargs={'parent_pk': self.object.pk})
        else:
            url = reverse('dashboard:catalogue-product-list')
        return self.get_url_with_querystring(url)
```

**urls.py:**

```
  urlpatterns += [
            path(
                'products/create/',
                self.myapps_catalogue_views.ProductCreateRedirectView.as_view(),
                name='catalogue-product-create'
            ),

            path(
                'products/create/<slug:product_class_slug>/<slug:metal_slug>/<slug:gemstone_slug>',
                self.myapps_catalogue_views.ProductCreateUpdateView.as_view(),
                name='catalogue-product-create'
            ),

        ]
```

**template (selected parts):**

```
<!--templates/oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_update.html-->
{% extends 'oscar/dashboard/layout.html' %}
{% load form_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block body_class %}{{ block.super }} create-page catalogue{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }} | {% trans "Products" %} | {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
    #omitted due to space constraints
{% endblock %}

{% block headertext %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block dashboard_content %}
    <form action="{% if request.GET.urlencode %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}{% endif %}" method="post" class="form-stacked wysiwyg fixed-actions" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-behaviour="tab-nav-errors" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if parent %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        {% url 'dashboard:catalogue-product' pk=parent.id as parent_url %}
                        {% blocktrans with title=parent.title %}
                            You are currently editing a product variant of
                            <a href="{{ parent_url }}">{{ title }}</a>.
                        {% endblocktrans %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="row">

            {% block tab_nav %}
                #omitted due to space constraints
            {% endblock tab_nav %}

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    {% block tab_content %}
                        {% block product_details %}
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="product_details">
                                <div class="table-header">
                                    <h3>{% trans "Product details" %}</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card card-body product-details">
                                    {% block product_details_content %}
                                        <span class="error-block">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</span>
                                        {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                                            {{ field }}
                                        {% endfor %}

                                        {% for field in form.primary_form_fields %}
                                            {% if 'attr' not in field.id_for_label %}
                                                {% include 'oscar/dashboard/partials/form_field.html' with field=field %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    {% endblock product_details_content %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endblock product_details %}

                        {% block product_categories %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock product_categories %}

                        {% block product_attributes %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock product_attributes %}

                        {% block product_images %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock product_images %}

                        {% block stockrecords %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock stockrecords %}

                        {% block child_products %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock child_products %}

                        {% block recommended_products %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock recommended_products %}

                        {% block seo %}
                            #omitted due to space constraints
                        {% endblock seo %}
                        {% block metal_attributes %}
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="metal_attributes">
                                {% block metal_attributes_content %}
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                        <caption>
                                            {% trans "Attributes" %}
                                            <span class="badge badge-success">
                                                {% trans "Metal Type:" %} {{ metal }}
                                            </span>
                                        </caption>
                                        {% for field in form %}
                                            {% if 'attr' in field.id_for_label %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        {% include "oscar/dashboard/partials/form_field.html" %}
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </table>
                                {% endblock metal_attributes_content %}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock metal_attributes %}
                    {% endblock tab_content %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        {% block fixed_actions_group %}
            <div class="fixed-actions-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <a href="{% url 'dashboard:catalogue-product-list' %}">
                            {% trans "Cancel" %}
                        </a>
                        {% trans "or" %}
                        {% if parent %}
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="action" type="submit" value="create-another-child" data-loading-text="{% trans 'Saving...' %}">
                                {% trans "Save and add another variant" %}
                            </button>
                        {% endif %}
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" name="action" type="submit" value="continue" data-loading-text="{% trans 'Saving...' %}">
                            {% trans "Save and continue editing" %}
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="action" type="submit" value="save" data-loading-text="{% trans 'Saving...' %}">
                            {% trans "Save" %}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {% if product %}
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endblock fixed_actions_group %}
    </form>
{% endblock dashboard_content %}
```

**Previews of the Template:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd inspect the page source to check the form action. I think that may be causing it to not send the form to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: Take a look at the `urls.py` file, and change the paths order. Remember that Django evaluate them in order and take the first expression that match the pattern.

Also noticed that you're using `request.GET.urlencode()` in form action, but that will return only the URL GET params. Try to add the correct page URL there instead.